# PHP psexec shell command is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, shell, psexec

Im using this command in php

```
exec("psexec \\\\192.168.1.3 -u myAccount -p myPassword -i cmd.exe /c START c:\file.doc 2>&1",$output); 
var_dump($output);
```

but the result is wrong

```
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(62) "'psexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"
  [1]=>
  string(31) "operable program or batch file."
}
```

Comment: error message seems clear

Comment: Are you running the PHP script from the cmd window, or from the webserver? The webserver may not have the same executable path as you do.

Comment: I Running from the webserver, I redownload and extracted in system32 it's work correctly

Answer (score 1):

make sure that psexec command working fine with your console.

See
[Click Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx)

Make sure that user permission and path too.

Comment: Im using this tool, working fine in cmd windows, but in PHP show errors

Comment: Ok then for quick fix, copy the PStools directory into your php application directory and then use
exec("MyDir\PSTools\psexec \\\\192.168.1.3 -u myAccount -p myPassword -i cmd.exe /c START c:\file.doc 2>&1",$output); 
I mean navigate to the directory using exec().

Comment: Just you need to copy the PSTools directory and paste that into your project directory and then navigate through directories to run the command like **exec("my_lib\my_files\PStools\psexec ............", $output)**

Comment: I redownload and extracted in system32 it's work correctly, thank you for interest